# What does ReadTime mean in HashMap lookup while doing benchmarking?

Tags: java, performance, hashmap, performance-testing

I am working on doing some performance test on insertion and read time on `HashMap` just for fun to see how the `HashMap` performance is coming as compared to other data structures.

I have a text file which contains 1 million english words with their frequencies in this format -

```
hello 100
world 5000
good 2000
bad 9000
...
```

Now I am reading this file line by line and storing it in `HashMap` so I  am able to measure the insertion performance with the below code.

```
Map<String, String> wordTest = new HashMap<String, String>();

try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(FILE_LOCATION);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
    // split the string on whitespace
    String[] splitString = line.split("\\s+");
    // now put it in HashMap as key value  pair
    wordTest.put(splitString[0].toLowerCase().trim(), splitString[1].trim());

    line = reader.readLine();
    }
    long endTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("Insertion Time: " +TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(endTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
}
```

Now I would also like to measure the read performance as well in the `HashMap`. I know how to get values from the HashMap but not sure with the read time what does it mean? It means how much time it takes to search  for one string from the HashMap?

Basically I am confuse after taking a look from this link - https://github.com/jpountz/tries/wiki/Benchmark. In this link they have `ReadTime` but not sure what does it mean?

So my question is given my problem, If I need to calculate `ReadTime` what does it mean in General? Should I benchmark how much time a single string lookup is taking from `HashMap` or something else?

Or In general, if I would like to measure ReadTime from HashMap how should I do it?

Comment: Why are you including file operation in the performance test?

Comment: @Braj: Where? Is there anything wrong? Can you suggest what wrong I am doing? You saying, startTime should be just above While loop?

Comment: You want check the performance of insertion in `HashMap` only. correct me if I am wrong. but the time is including file operations also.

Comment: Yes just the performance of insertion in HashMap? Then how would I do that? Any suggestions will help me in my testing. So it should be just above put method call and just below the end time as well. Right? And then aggregate it at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I never suggest you that it will give you a perfect result for benchmarking.
Its just a sample code to read-write random values in `HashMap`.

```
    String atoz = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ0123456789";

    Map<String, String> wordTest = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //write logic

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 24223400; i++) {
        int begin1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((atoz.length() - 1) + 1));
        int end1 = begin1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((atoz.length() - begin1) + 1));
        int begin2 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((atoz.length() - 1) + 1));
        int end2 = begin2 + (int) (Math.random() * ((atoz.length() - begin2) + 1));

        wordTest.put(atoz.substring(begin1, end1), atoz.substring(begin2, end2));
    }
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken:" + (endTime - startTime) + " ms to insert "
            + wordTest.size() + " records.");


    // Read logic  

    String atoz1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    int counter=0;
    long startTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 24223400; i++) {
        int begin1 = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((atoz1.length() - 1) + 1));
        int end1 = begin1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((atoz1.length() - begin1) + 1));

        if(wordTest.get(atoz1.substring(begin1, end1))==null){
            counter++;
        }
    }
    long endTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken:" + (endTime1 - startTime1) + " ms to read " + 24223400
            + " records." + " Success hit:"+counter);
```

output:

```
    Time taken:4440 ms to insert 1953 records.
    Time taken:2839 ms to read 24223400 records. Success hit:8743257
```

**Note:** All the key permutations are finished after 1953 records so try with other random strings and logic.

Comment: But you change everything from file concept as I am using file here. But in general what does ReadTime means while looking up from HashMap? Just a single string lookup and then benchmark that?

Comment: Its just a sample code to test the insertion time in `HashMap`. There is nothing extra operation involved in this code.

Comment: In the same way you can change the key as well as value.

Comment: Yeah makes sense.. How about the `ReadTime` what does it mean in general? Just a single string lookup and then benchmark it?

Comment: No never. I think in the say way you can use this program for read random value from map. search for 100000 random keys then take the average. find the hits. Let me code it for you.

Comment: Does it mean, those keys has to be in the HashMap while benchmarking or if it is not there then it is also fine?

Comment: Sorry I can't say about `benchmarking`. I can tell you just about the read-write performance logic.

Comment: Sure. Read code will help me a lot in getting the idea how it has  to be done.

Comment: I have updated my post. Please have a look and modify it as per your requirement.

Comment: Is it `==null` or !=null check should be there?

Comment: `HashMap#get()` return `null` if nothing is found in `map` because we have added values and we are sure that there is no `null` value.

Comment: you can use `containsKey()` also.